# How to interact with Adobe Flash Player using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, flash, webcam, interaction

I recently integrated a jQuery plugin which uses Flash to comunicate with the Webcam ( http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/ ). Is it possible to use JavaScript to retrieve the status of the Flash Player ? In other words: without recompiling the AS code and adding an extra callback, is it possible to know, using JavaScript, if the user pressed "Allow" or "Deny" in the Flash Player ? (indicating that the webcam is turned on)

Comment: It sounds impossible. Why don't you add some callbacks in the AS code? That's much easier.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll probably have to do that. I just wanted to know if there was an alternative before delving into AS :)

Comment: It would really be pretty painless to add those callbacks, if you have the AS source you're probably looking at about 10 mins of effort.